# JW Player not playing DAILYMOTION and VIMEO video but YOUTUBE Video works perfectly fine

Tags: javascript, html5-video, jwplayer, vimeo-api, dailymotion-api

JW Player is playing YOUTUBE Video perfectly fine but not playing DAILYMOTION and VIMEO video, even its play button dont even proceeds with the video.

Simply copy paste the whole code in Body Tag and output is there.

Below is the code in which Youtube, Dailymotion and Vimeo video.
Waiting for the response.

Thanking You,,,,, guys :)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/9ompKvFTEeKn+hIxOQulpA.js"></script>

    <h3>related</h3>
    <div id="related"></div>
    <h3>Youtube Video</h3>
    <div id="youtube_video"></div>
    <h3>Dailymotion Video</h3>
    <div id="dailymotion_video"></div>
    <h3>Vimeo Video</h3>
    <div id="vimeo_video"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jwplayer("related").setup({
                flashplayer: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                width: 760,
                height: 350,
                primary: "flash",
                html5player: "jwplayer.api.html5.js",
                'playlist.position': 'right',
                'playlist.size': '250',
                listbar: {
                    position: 'right',
                    size: 250
                },
                playlist: [
                    { apitype: "dailymotion", provider: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/dailymotion-2.0.swf", file: "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5q9zr.mp4" , title: "Big Buck Bunny", duration: "10:05"   },
                ],
                dailymotion: {
                    enableApiData: true
                }
            });

            jwplayer("youtube_video").setup({
                flashplayer: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                width: 300,
                height: 150,
                primary: "flash",
                html5player: "jwplayer.api.html5.js",
                playlist: [
                    {
                        file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYbiMJkpFXY", 
                        title: "Funny Cats Compilation", 
                    },
                ],
                tracks: [
                    {
                        file: "http://ghatasheh.com/alijw/carlin.srt", 
                        default: true
                    }
                ]
            });

            jwplayer("dailymotion_video").setup({
                flashplayer: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                width: 300,
                height: 150,
                primary: "flash",
                html5player: "jwplayer.api.html5.js",
                playlist: [
                    {
                        apitype: "dailymotion", 
                        provider: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/dailymotion-2.0.swf", 
                        file: "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xzdk8v_wordpress-instalations_tech.mp4", 
                        title: "Big Buck Bunny", 
                    },
                ],
                dailymotion: {
                    enableApiData: true
                }
            });

            jwplayer("vimeo_video").setup({
                flashplayer: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/jwplayer.flash.swf",
                width: 300,
                height: 150,
                primary: "flash",
                html5player: "jwplayer.api.html5.js",
                playlist: [
                    {
                        apitype: "vimeo", 
                        provider: "http://static.electroteque.org/swf/vimeo-2.0.swf", 
                        file: "vimeo.com/66349319.mp4", 
                        title: "Vimeo Video", 
                    },
                ],
                vimeo: {
                    enableApiData: true
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: We only support YouTube officially, nothing else, and a 3rd party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mystery there. JW Player supports YouTube videos, but does not support Dailymotion or Vimeo videos. To display those videos, you have to use their own player scripts, not JW Player.

From the JW Player FAQ:

> JW Player supports playback of multiple media formats: video files,
>   audio files, YouTube videos, RSS playlists and adaptive streams.

That's it. Nothing else.

I gather there are plugins available to make JW Player work with Dailymotion or Vimeo videos, but they're not part of the JW Player package, and are not supported. You would have to download and install these separately.

Comment: Thanks misterneutron for your response, but i the code above is from the documentation of the JWPLAYER`s enhaced plugin [http://jwplayer.electroteque.org/dailymotion] 
I just cant figure this out that the sample video works fine on their website as in the above mentioned link. But at my side its PLAY button is not  getting clicked.

Still, Waiting for the answer!
Thank You!

Comment: That's not a JW Player site. That's an Electroteque site. Take a look at the actual page coding - they're loading their own plugins, both their own JS files and their own customized CSS.

Comment: Yes i have already added these two library tooo....

    <script src="http://static.electroteque.org/js/jwplayer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.electroteque.org/css/global-0.52.css" />

but still its not clickable.
Here`s the link on which i have made sample page [http://mywebprojects.netii.net/learning_project/simple_jwplayer_cleancode.php]

Youtube works fine but still other two dont.

Comment: We only support YouTube officially, nothing else, and a 3rd party. We can't provide support for 3rd party add ons / plug ins, etc.

Comment: thank you for your confirmation.

Can you please guide a little about this [jwplayer.electroteque.org/dailymotion]. How are they able to embed dailymotion and vimeo with jwplayer.
I have gone through their documentation but still not able to get that done, here`s the link [mywebprojects.netii.net/learning_project/simple_jwplayer_cleancode.php].

Thanking You!

Comment: Sorry - we know about JW Player, but know nothing about Electroteque's plugin scripts. You'd have to ask Electroteque about them. There's a contact link on their site: http://jwplayer.electroteque.org/contact